# Area enclosed between the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=60-7x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area enclosed between the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=60-7x$.

I am completely new at this but I have tried and I believe that it should be between the numbers $0$ and $60$ is this right?

Comment: The area is between 810 and 820. If you show your work someone can help you spot the mistake.

Comment: Calculate intersections of your functions and integrate the function $60-7x-x^2$ with this limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good idea to draw the functions if possible(i.e if you know the graphs of the functions, and you should learn some basic graphs like lines,sin and cos, roots,etc.), then find the intersection points between the two function which are in this case $x=5,x=-12$ as the other answers show. Here is a graph of these functions

[image]

and as the graph shows $60-7x$ is above $x^2$ thus the area is $$\begin{align}
A=&\int_{-12}^{5}60-7x-x^2dx\\
=&60x-\frac{7x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}\mid_{-12}^{5}\\=&\frac{4913}{6}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Find where $y = x^2$ and $y = 60 - 7x$ *intersect*:

You can do this by setting the equations equal to one another and solving the resulting quadratic equation $$x^2 = 60 - 7x \iff x^2 +7x  - 60 = 0 $$ $$\iff (x+12)(x-5) = 0 $$ $$\iff \;x = -12, \;\;\text{or}\;\;x = 5$$

Use these values as your limits of integration, and calculate the integral of the area between the line $y = 60 - 7x$ and the parabola $y = x^2$ by integrating the function $$(60 -7x) -x^2$$

using those $x$-values as limits.

Note: We *subtract* from $y = 60-7x$, the function $\;y = x^2\;$ because for every $x\in (-12, 5),\;\;60 - 7x > x^2$.

This can easily be shown by ***graphing*** the two functions, which is always a good thing to do for problems like this. This helps determine the number of regions over which to integrate, if more than one such region exists, which function is the "upper" and which the "lower", and bounds of integration. WolframAlpha gives us:

[image]

That is, to compute the area of the region bound by $\;y = 60 - 7x\;$  and $\;y = x^2,\;$ between the values of intersection $\;x = -12\;$ to $\;x=5,\;$ compute $$\int_{-12}^5 (60 - 7x - x^2) \, dx$$

Comment: Does this make sense?  If $,F = \int (60 - 7x - x^2)\,dx\;$ then evaluate $F(5) - F(-12) = $ Area. So compute the integral, then determine its value at $5$, and subtract from that its value at $-12$.

Comment: Needs positive feedback! +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to find the area between two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

1. Find when $f(x) = g(x)$, calling the intersections $a$ and $b$. Assume $f(x) \ge g(x)$ over the interval $[a, b]$ (this will make sure the area is positive).
2. Find $$ \int_{a}^b f(x) - g(x) \; \mathrm dx$$

In your case, we have that:

$$ x^2 = 60 - 7x $$
$$ x^2 + 7x - 60 = 0 $$

The solutions are $-12$ and $5$, and we call these $a$ and $b$. Since $60 - 7x$ is greater over this interval, we integrate:

$$ \int_{-12}^{5} 60 - 7x - x^2 \; \mathrm dx $$
$$ \int_{-12}^{5} 60  \; \mathrm dx - \int_{-12}^{5} 7x  \; \mathrm dx - \int_{-12}^{5} x^2 \; \mathrm dx $$

Consider a rectangle with length $17$ ($|-12| + |5| = 17$) and height $60$ (the integrand). Now the area is $ 60 \cdot 17 = 1020 $.

$$ 1020 - 7\color{green}{\int_{-12}^{5} x  \; \mathrm dx} - \color{blue}{\int_{-12}^{5} x^2 \; \mathrm dx} $$

By the power rule of integration:

$$ \int x^n \; \mathrm dx = \frac{x^{n-1}}{n} $$

and the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$ \int_a^b f(x) = F(b) - F(a) \text{ where } F'(x) = f(x) $$

$$ 1020 - 7\color{green}{\left(\frac{5^2}{2} - \frac{(-12)^2}{2} \right)} - \color{blue}{\left(\frac{5^3}{3} - \frac{(-12)^3}{3}\right)} $$
$$ 1020 - 7\color{green}{(25/2 - 144/2)} - \color{blue}{(125/3 + 1728/3)} $$
$$ = 9683 / 3$$

Comment: Yes this I know but it is the calculation after that I get stuck with

Comment: @user1838781, I added more information. Do you know how to integrate functions such as $x^2$ and $x$? What exactly are you having trouble with.

Comment: After the integration I belive that your supposed to calculate so that in the end it's only a simple number

Comment: @user1838781, I've completed the problem by using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the power rule for integration. Do you understand how the results are derived now?

Comment: No I don't know how to integrate it. Is it something like: if I take it all together [60-7-2x] what now?

Comment: @user1838781, I've tried to highlight the relevant steps in my answer. You have to break up the integral (the integral of the sum is the same as the sum of the integrals, the same for difference). Then you use the power rule to find the indefinite integral, at which point you use the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate the definite integral.

Comment: I don't think that your aswer is correct, im supposed to use derivative

Comment: @user1838781, Finding the area between the curves requires the integral. There is no way to deal with this using derivatives, unless you mean to say that you're supposed to use derivatives to find the function $f'(x) = x$ (the derivative of $f(x)$ is $x$), in which case you are just guessing for the correct answer (integration is the anti-differentiation). Do you have an example of how this can be solved using derivatives?

Comment: No the only thing I have is the two curves and that they form an area that im supposed to find out with derivates